# how to manage and delete duplicate joined contacts?

Tags: contacts

How can i disjoin my contacts?

i do not know why but many of my contacts have like 10 similar joined contacts (because of multiple import i think from SIM  to phone and vice versa ) and i have to go to process of manually disjoining them one by one and then go to multiple delete and then select and delete them

I have tried a few top android contacts manager but i cannot get the 2 mentioned requested features?

Comment: Possible answer is _Link_ and _Unlink_ options in contacts itself.

Comment: It would help to know which Android OS version you are running, and on which device.

Answer (score -1):

just use this app, it will delete your duplicates
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.accaci&hl=en